# How to break foreach loop to stop executing else block inside?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How to stop executing else block number of items in array inside foreach loop? Is that possible, or should I change program logic?

Pseudocode is here to make clear what I want to do:

```
input = 2
array = [1,2,3,4,...]
foreach item in array
    if input equals 3
      logs MATCH
    else
      logs NOT MATCH // logs once for 1, not for 2, logs for 3,4,number of items
end foreach
```

I have tried with break, but I don't get desired effect, if I break else, on first run foreach loop will be stoped, and in that particular case, second item in array never will be tested.

Actuall code is bellow, but I hope that pseudo code is clear enough.

```
// take user input
$phone_number = '004913535030';
// initialize countrycodes
$countrycodes = [385,49,386];

// is number local number, one or zero zeros, two digit local or mobile code, and 6 or 7 digits?
if (preg_match('(^0*\d{0,2}\d{6,7}$)', $phone_number))
{
    // If yes, then we deal with local number, without country code prefix
    // Remove zeroes at begining if any, and add "+countrycode(385)." in front of clean number
    echo "local number";
    echo 'Original number is: ' . $phone_number . '<br>';
    echo 'Country code is not matched!';
    echo '<br>' . 'Stripped number is: ' . preg_replace("/^(0+)/", '', $phone_number);
    echo '<br>' . 'Formatted number is: ' . '+' . $countrycodes[0] . '.' . preg_replace("/^(0{1,}$countrycodes[0])|^($countrycodes[0])|^(0+)/",'',$phone_number);
}
else 
{   
    // bla bla, for each item in array check match, then strip number, and format it according to EPP RFC standard
    foreach($countrycodes as $countrycode )
    {
        // Do we have country code in phone number and number longer than 9 characters? Then some of EU members phone number
        // Clean number, remove zeroes at begining if any, and add "+countrycode." in front of clean number
        if (preg_match("/^(0{1,}$countrycode\d{8,})|^($countrycode\d{8,})/", $phone_number, $match[0]))
        {
            echo 'Original number is: ' . $phone_number . '<br>';
            echo 'Country code is matched ' . '<br>' . 'Country code is:' . $countrycode;
            //print_r($match);
            // strip country code and one or more preceding zeros
            echo '<br>' . 'Stripped number is: ' . preg_replace("/^(0{1,}$countrycode)|^($countrycode)|^(0+)/", '', $phone_number);
            echo '<br>' . 'Formatted number is: ' . '+' . $countrycode . '.' . preg_replace("/^(0{1,}$countrycode)|^($countrycode)|^(0+)/",'',$phone_number);
            // break
        }
        // HOW TO PREVENT EXECUTING OF ELSE BLOCK NUMBER OF ITEMS IN COUNTRYCODES ARRAY TIMES BUT PRINT WHEN COUNTRYCODE NOT MATCHED?
        else
        {
            echo "Not an EU number";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to check the phone number with all the country codes and print the result once if not matched. I think you don't need a else condition. You should try this:

```
$matched = false;
 foreach($countrycodes as $countrycode )
    {
        // Do we have country code in phone number and number longer than 9 characters? Then some of EU members phone number
        // Clean number, remove zeroes at begining if any, and add "+countrycode." in front of clean number
        if (preg_match("/^(0{1,}$countrycode\d{8,})|^($countrycode\d{8,})/", $phone_number, $match[0]))
        {
            echo 'Original number is: ' . $phone_number . '<br>';
            echo 'Country code is matched ' . '<br>' . 'Country code is:' . $countrycode;
            //print_r($match);
            // strip country code and one or more preceding zeros
            echo '<br>' . 'Stripped number is: ' . preg_replace("/^(0{1,}$countrycode)|^($countrycode)|^(0+)/", '', $phone_number);
            echo '<br>' . 'Formatted number is: ' . '+' . $countrycode . '.' . preg_replace("/^(0{1,}$countrycode)|^($countrycode)|^(0+)/",'',$phone_number);
$matched = true;            
break;
        }

    }
if (!$matched) {
echo "Not an EU number";
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. That's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but I'll take a stab.

Do you want to stop the loop from processing if you find a match? Then the command you're looking for is `break;`:

```
foreach($countrycodes as $countrycode )
{
    if (preg_match("/^(0{1,}$countrycode\d{8,})|^($countrycode\d{8,})/", $phone_number, $match[0]))
    {
        echo 'Original number is: ' . $phone_number . '<br>';
        echo 'Country code is matched ' . '<br>' . 'Country code is:' . $countrycode;
        echo '<br>' . 'Stripped number is: ' . preg_replace("/^(0{1,}$countrycode)|^($countrycode)|^(0+)/", '', $phone_number);
        echo '<br>' . 'Formatted number is: ' . '+' . $countrycode . '.' . preg_replace("/^(0{1,}$countrycode)|^($countrycode)|^(0+)/",'',$phone_number);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Not an EU number";
    }
}
```

The `break;` command will stop processing the loop.

Comment: I have tried with break, but foreach will run for first item, and after it hits match will break. Maybe I should try with matches count or something similar.